# How to move up and down

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a ship for alien invaders move up and down but can't seem to make it properly work without messing something up.

With my code below what would I need to add?

alien_invasion.py:

```
import sys
import pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    #Initialize pygame, settings, and screen object
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    #Draw the ship
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)



    #Start the main loop for the game.
    while True:
        #Watch for keyboard and mouse events
        gf.check_events(ship)
        ship.update()
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship)


run_game()
```

ship.py:

```
import pygame

class Ship():
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        """Initialize teh ship and set its starting position"""
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings

    #Load teh ship image and get its rect
    self.image = pygame.image.load('ship.bmp')
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

    #Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen
    self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
    self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

    # Store a decimal value for the ship's center.
    self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)

    # Movement flag
    self.moving_right = False
    self.moving_left = False

def update(self):
    """Update the ship's postion based on the movement flag"""
    # Update the ship's center value, not the rect.
    if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
        self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
    if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
        self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

    # Update rect object from self.center
    self.rect.centerx = self.center

def blitme(self):
    """Draw the ship at its current location"""
    self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

game_fuction.py:

```
import sys

import pygame

def check_keydown_events(event, ship):
    """Responds to keypresses"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True

def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    """Respoinds to key releases"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False

def check_events(ship):
    """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        check_keydown_events(event, ship)

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        check_keyup_events(event, ship)

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship):
    """Update images on the screen and flip to the new screen"""
    #Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    ship.blitme()

#Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
pygame.display.flip()
```

settings.py:

```
class Settings():
    """A Class to store all settings for ALein INvasion"""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game's settings"""
        #screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (255,255,255)

    # Ship Settings
    self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5
```

This is a project from Python Crash Course.
This certain project says

> Make a game that begins with a rocket in the center of the screen.
>   Allow the player to move the rocket up, down, left, or right using the
>   four arrow keys. Make sure the rocket never moves beyond any edge or
>   the screen.

Comment: You say "can't seem to make it properly work without messing something up" - please describe how it messes up, and what you expect it to do instead, as that's a lot of code to look through. Oh, and in `game_fuction.py` your `elif`s are at the wrong indentation - is that a typo?

Comment: You act on the keydown, which means that when the key already *is* down, there is no event invoked - this prevents the *continuous* movement. What you can do for example is initialize a movement on keydown (ie. like a while loop which gets continously updated) and break it on keyup.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't typed this in to check, but I have solved similar problems/projects in pygame. It looks like you need to modify the code in two places:

1) Catch the events of pressing the down key and the up keys.
This is probably something like:

```
 # from your game_function.py
def check_keydown_events(event, ship):
    """Responds to keypresses"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        ship.moving_down = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        ship.moving_up = True

def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    """Respoinds to key releases"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        ship.moving_down = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        ship.moving_up = False
```

2) Your original ship class to process the actual movement.
This should look something like:

```
# Movement flag
self.moving_right = False
self.moving_left = False
self.moving_down = False
self.moving_up = False

def update(self):
    """Update the ship's postion based on the movement flag"""
    # Update the ship's center value, not the rect.
    if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
        self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
    if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
        self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
    if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom > self.screen_rect.bottom: 
        self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
    if self.moving_up and self.rect.top < self.screen_rect.top:
        self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

    # Update rect object from self.center - might need to be changed now to handle
    # movement in two directions properly.
    if self.moving_up or self.moving_down:
        self.rect.centery = self.center
    if self.moving_left or self.moving_right:
        self.rect.centerx = self.center
```

Comment: I've tried something like this but when i try to continuously move the ship up and down it wont allow me

Comment: This is probably to do with needing to refactor what happens with the self.center which doesn't currently have an x and a y and needing to handle them separately.  Show me what you've tried and I'll see if I can just make all the changes and give you a working version.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've cracked it - this solution is now working:

settings.py

```
class Settings:
    """A Class to store all settings for ALien INvasion"""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game's settings"""
        #screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (255,255,255)

    # Ship Settings
    ship_speed_factor = 1.5
```

game_functions.py

```
import sys

import pygame

def check_keydown_events(event, ship):
    """Responds to keypresses"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        ship.moving_down = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        ship.moving_up = True

def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    """Responds to key releases"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        ship.moving_down = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        ship.moving_up = False

def check_events(ship):
    """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ship)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship):
    """Update images on the screen and flip to the new screen"""
    #Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    ship.blitme()

    #Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
    pygame.display.flip()
```

ship.py

```
import pygame

class Ship:
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        """Initialize teh ship and set its starting position"""
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings

        #Load the ship image and get its rect
        self.image = pygame.image.load('ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        #Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

        # Store a decimal value for the ship's x and y center.
        self.centerx = float(self.rect.centerx)
        self.centery = float(self.rect.centery)

        # Movement flag
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_down = False
        self.moving_up = False

    def update(self):
        """Update the ship's postion based on the movement flag"""
        # Update the ship's center value, not the rect.
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.centerx += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.centerx -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom < self.screen_rect.bottom:
            self.centery += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_up and self.rect.top > self.screen_rect.top:
            self.centery -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

        # Update rect object from self.center - might need to be changed now to handle
        # movement in two directions properly.
        if self.moving_up or self.moving_down:
            self.rect.centery = self.centery
        if self.moving_left or self.moving_right:
            self.rect.centerx = self.centerx

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the ship at its current location"""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

alien_invasion.py

```
import sys
import pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    #Initialize pygame, settings, and screen object
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    #Draw the ship
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)

    #Start the main loop for the game.
    while True:
        #Watch for keyboard and mouse events
        gf.check_events(ship)
        ship.update()
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship)


run_game()
```

Actually, all I did was to implement all of the changes that I described and eliminate a few basic errors in layout/syntax.  Note that I added a better quit function to close the graphics canvas when you click the red button.

If this solution also works for you then please mark it as the answer so that I can get enough reputation here on stack flow.

Comment: As I run alien_invasion.py, it creates an error: "local variable 'ai_settings' referenced before assignment". But when I write 
"global ai_settings" after the top of the function run_game(), it writes me: "name 'ai_settings' is not defined". How to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it was top result when I ran into the same problem. Just want to show how I ended up doing it.

alien_invasion.py keydown and keyup check events:

```
def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
    """respond to keypresses"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        self.ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
        self.ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        self.ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
        self.ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        self.ship.moving_up = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        self.ship.moving_down = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
        sys.exit()


def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
    """respond to key releases"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        self.ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
        self.ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        self.ship.moving_left = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
        self.ship.moving_left = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        self.ship.moving_up = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        self.ship.moving_down = False
```

ship.py

```
import pygame


class Ship:
    """A class to manage the ship"""

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """initialize the ship and set its starting position"""
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        # load the ship image and get its rect
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen
        # self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
        self.rect.center = self.screen_rect.center

        # store a decimal value for the ship's horizontal position
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

        # movement flag
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False

    def update(self):
        """update the ship's position on the movement flag"""
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.x += self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.x -= self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_up and self.rect.top > 0:
            self.y -= self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom < self.screen_rect.bottom:
            self.y += self.settings.ship_speed

        # update rect object from self.x
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def blitme(self):
        """draw the ship at its current location"""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

I added the moving_up and moving_down plus had to add the self.rect.y for the y axis.
The ship cannot move past the top of the screen or the bottom.
Hope this helps anyone who googled the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a runnable solution for 2nd edition of the book.

***alien_invasion.py*** as below:

```py
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship


class AlienInvasion:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Alien Invasion')
        self.ship = Ship(self)

    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            self._check_event()
            self.ship.update()
            self._update_screen()
            pygame.display.flip()

    def _check_event(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_event(event)

    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.ship.moving_up = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.ship.moving_down = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit()

    def _check_keyup_event(self, event):
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.ship.moving_down = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.ship.moving_up = False

    def _update_screen(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

***settings.py***

```py
class Settings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
        self.ship_speed = 1.5
```

***ship.py***

```
import pygame


class Ship:
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False

    def update(self):
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.x += self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.x -= self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_up and self.rect.top > self.screen_rect.top:
            self.y -= self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom < self.screen_rect.bottom:
            self.y += self.settings.ship_speed
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```